# script.aculo.us autocomplete stuck behind input elements

Tags: ajax, scriptaculous, z-index

I've got several script.aculo.us Ajax.Autocomplete controls on a page and when the drop down div is rendered it's always stuck behind the other text boxes on the page, no matter what I do with zIndex and positioning. The problem occurs in IE and FF. Anyone else run into this? Am I missing something, or is this just life with this control?

Comment: Can you give a sample? I have used Prototype/Scriptaculous and Autocomplete's always worked for me. ;D

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my attempt to strip everything down to the basics to post an example, I actually managed to fix it. Two part solution. Firstly, I had to ditch all the z-index definitions in my controls. They were part of the problem. Secondly, I had to go into the show function of the autocomplete control and add: "update.style.zIndex = 1000;" to the function. My autocomplete drop down divs are now above the controls as needed. Perhaps there's another way I could have done things to avoid modifying the script.aculo.us code, but I'm just happy it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Four pages of google'ing, and a bit of time hacking source code later ... Ok, so this may be a year old, but I figured out how to do it for version 1.8.3, and this is for whoever else bumps into this.

**To get multiple div's to go on top of each other via the z-index:**

First, you need a global variable. i.e. :

```
var global_zindex
```

then when you initialise the new draggable, in the onStart, give increment it:

```
onStart : function(){
  zIndex++;
},
```

Now we edit dragdrop.js:435 to look like this:

```
  this.element.style.zIndex = global_zindex //this.originalZ; // HACK HACK HACK
```

and bam, the div's pile correctly suddenly. This took so long, I had to post this here.